# Does .gitignore work on commit, push, or upon reaching the server?

Tags: git, gitignore

Say I have a `.gitignore` to ignore all `.class` files.

Are these files kept out of the remote origin when...

- I commit/add my files locally? Does my `git` look for a `.gitignore` when add/commit is used, and based on what it says, removes things from the commit?
- I push my commits? Does `git` git only push files that aren't being described in the `.gitignore`?
- It reaches the origin? Does the server that is holding the git repository keep out files based on it's `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I commit/add my files locally? Does my git look for a .gitignore when add/commit is used, and based on what it says, removes things from the commit?

[`git add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) ignores files and directories based on the rules expressed in [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). [`git commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) doesn't care about your `.gitignore`. It creates a new commit in the local repository using the information already prepared by `git add` and `git rm` (and other `git` commands) into the index.

[`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) is the command you can use to remove a file and record into the index you want to stop tracking it. If you have already removed the file from the working tree you can also use `git add` to record its removal into the index.

> I push my commits? Does git git only push files that aren't being described in the .gitignore?

[`git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) also doesn't care about your `.gitignore` because it doesn't work with files. It sends to the remote repository information that already exists in the local repository. If the file you want to ignore is already there then it will go to the remote repository too

If you have files in the repository and you want them to not be tracked any more you have to add their names (or wildcards that match their names) into `.gitignore` **and** use `git rm` to add the removal request into the index, to be processed on the next commit.

The versions of those files that already exist in the repository (local and remote) are not deleted. You have to rewrite the history for that but rewriting history on a repository used by many persons is not recommended.

> It reaches the origin? Does the server that is holding the git repository keep out files based on it's .gitignore?

Everything that's in the commits you push reach the remote repository. But in order for `git` to respect `.gitignore` when your co-workers check the project out on their computers, you have to add the `.gitignore` file to the repository; and commit, and push, of course, to let the `.gitignore` file find its way to their systems. There is no "my `.gitignore`" and "its `gitignore`". The `.gitingore` file must be added to the repository (and committed every time it changes) in order to have effect for everybody.

Comment: `git status` also respects the ignored files. But other than that, there isn’t anything else.

Comment: I thought `git add` can stage a file delete, though, when the file is tracked but missing from disk.

Comment: @jpmc26 You are right, `git add` will stage the deletion of a missing file. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I commit/add my files locally?

Yes. A `.gitignore` is applied as soon as it is exists, for all files not yet added to the index.
If an ignored file was already added to the index (before the .gitignore was created/updated), then that file **will be part of the commit**. You would need to remove it manually first: `git rm --cached -- afileToIgnore`

Don't forget to add and commit the `.gitignore` file itself, for those ignore rules to be valid not only on your local repo, but on any clone of that repo as well.

> Does git git only push files that aren't being described in the .gitignore?

Yes, unless that file was added before the `.gitignore`, or if it was force added.
A `git add --force -- afile` will add a file to the index even if it is supposed to be ignored.

> Does the server that is holding the git repository keep out files based on it's `.gitignore`?

No: the server will just add the `.gitignore` to the repo, without any side-effect the other versioned files.